# How can I calculate the entropy reduction in my system I'm going to introduce?

Tags: pbkdf2

I am the creator of LessPass, a deterministic password generator.

The core of LessPass is not very complicated.

I have 2 methods `calc_entropy` and `render_password`:

[image: lesspass core]

`calc_entropy` transforms the master password + site + login into a very large integer that I call entropy (I don't know if it's the right term, but it represents my amount of randomness in my system). It uses pbkdf2 100k iterations.

`render_password` uses/consumes this entropy. I have a loop that comes to pick a character from a list of desired characters thanks to the remainder of a long division.

To be sure to have a char for each rule (lowercase, uppercase, digits, symbols) I always pick 1 character for each rule and I insert it in a pseudo-random way in the generated password.

The detail of the algo with an example is available [here](https://github.com/lesspass/lesspass/wiki/Overview-of-Password-Generation).

---

LessPass allows its users to save on a server profiles for their generated passwords to avoid remembering sites rules. A profile looks like this:

```
{
    "login": "my_login",
    "site": "www.exemple.org",
    "lowercase": false,
    "uppercase": false,
    "symbols": false,
    "digits": true,
    "counter": 1,
    "length": 6
}
```

I would like to introduce a new functionality by allowing the import of passwords from other password managers.

Imagine that my old password for www.example.org is **foobar**.

I can generate a very large number which after passing in the function `render_password` generated the password **foobar** (randomly generated entropy).

I would like to store in the password profile the difference between the actual entropy and a randomly generated entropy which goes through render_password generates **foobar**.

To generate the old password, I calculate the entropy, apply the diff then render the password.

I did a naive poc [here](https://github.com/lesspass/lesspass/blob/master/sandbox/test_import.py)

If you have read me so far thank you!

---

**My question:** to what extent do I increase the brutuceforcability of the master password if an attacker stole the LessPass database (he knows the diff) and stole the user's password (he knows **foobar**) compared just knowing the **foobar** password?

Comment: Tangential question: what if the user needs to change the master password?

Answer (score 1):

So basically, this is a form of plain-text attack against your algorithm.

The question is how easy it is to guess your integer. If I know "foobar" and the new password, then I can create a set of equations that try to determine the original integer. As long as the integer is larger (in qty bits) than the password (the actual information in the password), then I can never really calculate the actual integer.

I might, however, get enough information to make the integer 'less random'.   That sounds abstract, but let me give a very simple example.

I try to determine the value of `x`, which is an element of [1 - 10]. The original brute force would need me to test 10 values. However, I know that the remainder of x/3=2.  That means that x is an element of {2,5,8}. So I now have to test 3 values, instead of 10.

How that exactly works out for your algorithm, and whether you have sufficient entropy left requires quite a bit of calculation in the realm of information theory. And to be honest, my information theory is a bit too rusty for this.

Another question is whether the entropy is sufficient. Compared to what? A completely random password? or "qwerty123"?

I realize that I have not answered your question, but instead made the problem slightly larger. Or I may even have completely misunderstood the question. Sorry for that.